# Docusign: Verify HMAC key from header response with the secret key

Tags: docusignapi

I am working with Docusign connect and planning to use HMAC keys to authenticate the messages. I am referring https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/connect-hmac#example-hmac-workflow link.

I find few terms confusing in the documentation. Attaching the code snippet from the doc for python.

```
def ComputeHash(secret, payload):
  import hmac
  import hashlib
  import base64
  hashBytes = hmac.new(secret, msg=payload, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()
  base64Hash = base64.b64encode(hashBytes)
  return base64Hash;

def HashIsValid(secret, payload, verify):
  return verify == ComputeHash(secret,payload)
```

Can you explain what payload(didn't understand exactly what it is), secret (I am guessing the secret key) and verify means from the above code and how do I verify my secret key with **X-Docusign-Signature-1** which I get from response header?

My code:

```
message = request.headers
hashBytes = hmac.new(secret_key.encode('utf-8'), msg=message.encode('utf-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
base64Hash = base64.b64encode(hashBytes)
```

**[Edited]**

I found the solution on my own. Please read the first answer. I have explained it in details.

Comment: As for the first part of your question, payload is the message being hashed, secret is the secret key, and verify (in `HashIsValid`) is a precomputed hash that you're verifying is the hash corresponding to `payload`.

Comment: Thanks Calvin for responding. I still have a doubt..

By message being hashed means the header of the request or the data which is in XML?
Also, I am still not clear with verify as I just have secret key with meand nothing else.

Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I spent entire day trying to figure out a way to get done with this but no luck. My GCP cloud functions crashed every time..

I tried something like this:



hashBytes = hmac.new(secret_key.encode('utf-8'), msg=request.header.encode('utf-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
base64Hash = base64.b64encode(hashBytes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion.
*Payload* is "The entire body of the POST request is used, including line endings."
This is what you're encoding here using a Hash (HMAC) function.

SHA256 HMAC digest take in an the array of bytes (payload) and a secret (some key to use for encryption) and produces some encrypted version of the payload that can later be verified.

I highly recommend you ensure you first understand how the Connect webhook works without using HAMC encoding. This feature is meant to secure your application and it's a bit more complex. If you first get it working without it - you'll get a better grasp of what's going on (as well as feel a bit better about accomplishing a subtask).
Once you have it working, you can add the HMAC to make it secure and it will be easier at that point.

Comment: Thank Inbar.. I already have my system working. Actually, I am using GCP cloud functions as my listener and I am able to get the XML body through Docusign Connect. Now, I just have to add HMAC feature.

Comment: I am doing this as per your comment but still my cloud function crashes. Please highlight if I am doing something wrong here.. -->.      
message = request.headers
hashBytes = hmac.new(secret_key.encode('utf-8'), msg=message.encode('utf-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
base64Hash = base64.b64encode(hashBytes)

Comment: We have some code in GitHub that can help.
https://github.com/docusign/connect-node-listener-gcloud
Shows you how to use Google Cloud Node code to listen to Connect webhook events using HMAC as well

Comment: Hey Inbar.. I have one question. Does body of the POST request consists of header or XML  body response from Docusign connect  or both? @Inbar

Comment: XML body. If this answered your question - please mark as answered.

Comment: I cant understand the verify parameter...

Comment: it's the Boolean, the return value, true/false. The code can probably be refactored to use more modern PHP style where the return value doesn't have to be named.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem.

```
expected_signature = request.headers['X-Docusign-Signature-1']
message = request.data      # It is already in bytes. No need to encode it again.
hashBytes = hmac.new(secret_key.encode('utf-8'), msg=message, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
actual_signature = base64.b64encode(hashBytes)
hmac.compare_digest(actual_signature.decode('utf-8'),expected_signature):
```